# IF nesting formula, showing "too many arguments" error message

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

Given the following formula:

`=IF(D7="ACCOMMODATION","$220","",IF(D7="DINNER","$52.80","",IF(D7="LUNCH","$31.00","",IF(D7="BREAKFAST","$27.55","",IF(D7="INCIDENTALS","$19.70","")))))`

`D7` cell has a drop down list, the intent is for the selected list item to correspond with a price.

Examples:

- `D7` has dinner selected. `E7`will show `$52.80`
- `D7` has lunch selected. `E7` will show `$31.00`

Comment: How does "not working" manifest? Wrong result? No result? Error message? Please edit your question, provide a data sample and the expected result. When you have done that, post a comment to alert those that are following the question.

Comment: Error is quit obvious since you have ignored the basics of Nested IF !

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your formula to get rid of the extra `,""` (after 220, 52.80, 31.00, 27.55)

```
=IF(D7="ACCOMMODATION","$220",IF(D7="DINNER","$52.80",IF(D7="LUNCH","$31.00",IF(D7="BREAKFAST","$27.55",IF(D7="INCIDENTALS","$19.70","")))))
```

If you want actual numbers instead of text that look like numbers remove the quotations around your dollars and the dollar signs:

```
=IF(D7="ACCOMMODATION",220,IF(D7="DINNER",52.8,IF(D7="LUNCH",31,IF(D7="BREAKFAST",27.55,IF(D7="INCIDENTALS",19.7,"")))))
```

Consider learning the `=vlookup()` formula, it will be a lot cleaner than what you have.

Comment: I had seen the =vlookup() formula before, i will have to learn it properly. Thanls for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

When nesting IF statements, the syntax is

=IF(Condition, Do when True, if(next condition, Do when True, do when false))

You have supplied the "do when false" and THEN you provide the next IF statement. That won't work. Here is the formula cleaned up:

```
=IF(D7="ACCOMMODATION","$220",IF(D7="DINNER","$52.80",IF(D7="LUNCH","$31.00",IF(D7="BREAKFAST","$27.55",IF(D7="INCIDENTALS","$19.70",""))))
```

Note 1: If you want to return numbers, don't put them inside double quotes, just use the numbers without quotes and format the cell as a currency.

```
=IF(D7="ACCOMMODATION",220,IF(D7="DINNER",52.8,IF(D7="LUNCH",31,IF(D7="BREAKFAST",27.55,IF(D7="INCIDENTALS",19.7,"")))))
```

Note 2: You could set up a table with the words in one column and the values in the next column, then use Vlookup to look up the values. That would be much easier to maintain than the nested IF formula

Note 3: If you use Excel with an Office 365 license or Excel 2019, you can use the new IFS() function. This function does not require any nesting.

```
=IFS(D7="ACCOMMODATION",220,D7="DINNER",52.8,D7="LUNCH",31,D7="BREAKFAST",27.55,D7="INCIDENTALS",19.7,TRUE,"")
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, I see where i went wrong! 

Appreciate the help :)

Comment: If this solved your issue, please mark the answer as explained in the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

The [other](https://superuser.com/q/1468499/150988#1468505) two [answers](https://superuser.com/q/1468499/150988#1468506) explained the correct way to use `IF`
and mentioned `VLOOKUP`
as an alternative approach to using nested `IF` functions. 
As teylyn mentioned, `VLOOKUP` requires the use of a 2×5 array
to hold the five words and the five numbers. 
If your values are subject to change,
or if the list is likely to get much larger,
that is probably a good approach.

Here’s a formula that is self-contained,
but adopts the logic of a table lookup (i.e., what `VLOOKUP` does):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({220,52.8,31,27.55,19.7}, MATCH(D7,{"ACCOMMODATION","DINNER","LUNCH","BREAKFAST","INCIDENTALS"},0)), "")
```

The

```
MATCH(D7,{"ACCOMMODATION","DINNER","LUNCH","BREAKFAST","INCIDENTALS"},0)
```

part checks whether `D7` is one of those five words,
and returns 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 — or a `#N/A` error if it’s any other value. 
The

```
INDEX({220,52.8,31,27.55,19.7}, number)
```

part
returns 220, 52.8, 31, 27.55 or 19.7 if the *number* is 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5. 
And the

```
=IFERROR(blah blah blah, "")
```

gives you a blank
if the formula returns an error (i.e., if `D7` is not one of the five words).